# Could not get the Microsoft Azure storage account settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage

I'm trrying to publish an ASP.NET MVC project to azure.
In other computer i do this without problems, but in mine I don't.

The following error appears when publishing in Visual Studio 2013 :

```
Could not get the Microsoft Azure storage account settings for
'account-name' needed to configure an application module.
Please check your network connection and verify that the account exists.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show *where* you're getting this error: The portal? PowerShell? Visual Studio? Elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Is your project using Azure SDK 2.6 but you also have Azure SDK 2.7 installed? I had the same error and upgrading my cloud project to Azure SDK 2.7 seemed to fix it.